# Update 18.04 latest update hosing YouTube & Keyboard Input

Tags: 18.04, updates, keyboard, youtube

After lastest updating (17 April 2021), YouTube videos are starting and stopping - with no input from the user. Also my key board is freezing, and requires a reboot to start working again, i.e. keyboard. I'm also getting a zero with a dash through it, flashing on my screen - which interferes with me reading the screen, it's about 2 1/2 by 2 1/2 inches square (i.e. the square), with the zero dashed through.

Any help with this matter would greatly be appreciated. (I think this is the worst update I've experienced, in my many years of using Ubuntu, IMHO.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the behavior?  Are you sure you aren't seeing an overlay of some kind?  It sounds to me like the keyboard has a stuck key or something of that nature.

Comment: Please edit in your hardware specifications, namely graphics. I suspect you have Nvidia, were using manually installed drivers and the kernel update removed them.

Comment: Yes, think you Nmath and ChanganAuto; apparently I did have a malfunction keyboard; it just happened to malfuction after my very recent update to 18.04. Could you guys please tell me how to erase this post? I don't want individuals to think that the latest update to 18.04 is terrible - when it was just my mistake, the operator.